# How to fetch Kettle Trans execution results which are triggered by java application

Tags: kettle

I have successfully wrote a java program sending a ktr file to a remote Kettle platform to execute. The java program will load tasks in database and sending a related ktr to Kettle to execute. My problem is that I do not know how to get the Kettle Trans execution results for this task gracefully, cause I don't know how to filter out the trans logs by a certain task.

My current solution is to read the Ketlle Trans Log, one of the database log tables generate by Kettle itself.

The problem in this solution is since that all the fields and related data are provided by Kettle, I cannot tell which log is related to which task. So I have to rename transname in the transmeta with the task id, and then the task id will then be passed into the Trans Log table in the transname field. Through this way I can get the related log record by the task id.

```
private void startClusterTrans(String repoConnectStr, String transName, String taskId) throws PlatformException {
    Repository repository = null;
    TransMeta transMeta = null;
    try {
        repository = getKettleRepository(repoConnectStr);

        // 1: find the trans to execute by transName
        transMeta = findTransMeta(transName, repository);

        // 2: set the trans name with task id
        //    later the taksId will be passed to transname field in the trans log table
        transMeta.setName(taskId);
        TransExecutionConfiguration transExecutionConfiguration = new TransExecutionConfiguration();
        transExecutionConfiguration.setLogLevel(LogLevel.BASIC);
        transExecutionConfiguration.setExecutingClustered(true);
        ...
        transExecutionConfiguration.setVariables(transMeta);

        Trans.executeClustered(transMeta, transExecutionConfiguration);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new PlatformException(e);
    }
}
```

I think this method is not gracefully. Firstly, I have to scan the database every some seconds and cause database pressure. Secondly The transname will be changed if the trans is executed in cluster mode.

**Would anyone tell me if there is some other common way to filter the trans execution results?  I hope the way to fetch the results will be the same when trans is executed in local, remote and cluster mode.**

**To elaborate my problem, let's take cluster mode for example.** I start a java task #1001 , which will execute a foo.ktr in a cluster mode. I have 1 master and 2 slaves in this situation. After the execution, there will be 3 records generated in trans log table. Sadly I don't know how to link the 3 trans logs to my task #1001.

Now my workaround is that before send foo.ktr to cluster, I change the transname of the transmeta to be task #1001, and after execution, the transname field for the 3 trans records in the trans log table will look like 1001 (my-cluster-sth) ; 1001 (my-cluster: slave1) ; 1001 (my-cluster: slave2) . So I have to use "LIKE" key word to link these 3 records to my task.  I don't think this is a good way. The 2 concerns are alread mentioned above.

Comment: What do you call the Trans execution results? It may be the content of the fields as you see when you press the preview column. It may also be the copy of the small table you see at the bottom of spoon telling you the number of input and output records.

Comment: Do you want it dynamically (as the transformation is running) or historically (every morning to look if the nightly load went ok) ?

Comment: Thanks AlainD. Actually both the running and the historical info are required. The logs in the bottom of spoon ui can also be found in database. But my problem is that my java program will create a task to call Kettle to run a same trans every one hour. Imagine that after a busy night and in the next morning, I have no idea which task is successfully executed since there is no strict mapping relationships between the task generated by java program and the trans executed in Kettle.

Answer (score 0):

Please upvote http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-16549 and http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-10912.

If I do understand what you are aiming at, in a foreseeable future you 'll need to know the values of the parameters with which the transformation was run. So, upvote also http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-16550.

Comment: Thanks AlainD, I have read the 3 tickets carefully and found #PDI-16550 may be a workaround but still not quite straight to my problem. I have added an example in my question for that there is a word length limit in comment.